# IE8 freezes on click of close (X) button in modal window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, applet, java

we are using the applets in our client side . i'm facing a weird issue on IE8 .

Description : 
             IE8 freezes on closing of modal window using close button**(X default close button provided by IE)** which contains applet to display menu items .

i'm using JRE 1.6_18 (note : this issue is not observed with any other 1.4 series JRE , applet is compiled using JDk 1.4 )

one more thing i have observed is when i check "enable next generation java plugin" in control panel >>java>>advance>>java plugin >>enable next generation java plugin this issue is not simulating , but if i check that some other issues in our application arises .

we are using CLASS_ID= `clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93`

can any one tell me how can i over come this problem ?

Comment: thanks for your suugestions Andrew Thompson , i will follow the suggestions .

Comment: hi all , please comment on this